# iOS how to avoid notifications when opening customized app icon(shortcut)

Tags: ios, shortcut, appicon

I want to customize all my app icons, I have created a new shortcut, selected

Run App > below Open App > Selected app

Then I went to Screen time > See all activity > Selected shortcut’s > Disable notifications

But I still got the pop up when opening the customized app icon/shortcut

Then I tried creating an automation but without success either way.

Comment: You title says "how to avoid notifications" and your description says "I want to customize all my app icons". I'm having a hard time understanding the relationship between the title of the posting and the content of the posting, and thus the question, with the consequence that  I don't follow what you are asking.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.